# Firebase get a document method doesn't work more than once

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

The following code to get a document from Firestore used to work perfectly then at some point of adding Firebase hosting and functions it started to work only once after I initialize localhost or remote host. The code breaks on await docRef.get(), I am not sure what the error is since I don't know how to log errors on a website.

I am not sure what would cause this. Can anyone lead me.
Also here's what I know,

1. Creating, setting documents is completely fine, even on multiple.
2. Firestore Rules isn't denying my access requests.

```
async receive(code) {
        const docRef = firestore.collection("delivers").doc(code);
        let document = await docRef.get();
//an alert here dont work after the first time of it working
        if (document && document.exists) {
            return document.data().message.toString();
        } else {
            return "Invalid Code";
        }
    }`
```

Answer (score 0):

I thought of starting and working my way up from what I already had, the send document code, so I am not sure why it broke but currently the following code works instead.

```
const docRef = firestore.collection("delivers").doc(code);
        // alert(code);
        docRef.get().then( (document) => {
            if (document && document.exists) {
                alert(document.data().message.toString());
            } else {
                return "Invalid Code";
            }
        });
```

which is basically the same thing as before. I am confused

Answer (score 0):

Based of your comments these are some reasons that may be an issue:

1. You mentioned "localhost", and you are making calls to Firestore in Firebase's Emulator but only the hosting is up and running.
2. You function is async but you don't have `await` wherever you are calling it from as in the second case when you directly used promise rather than adding it in a function, it worked. You can actually write a function this way:

```
async function receive (code) { 
  return firestore.collection("delivers").doc(code).then((docSnapshot) => {
    if (document && document.exists) {
      return document.data().message.toString();
      //PS: you don't need toString() if the field is already a string in Firestore
    } else {
      return "Invalid Code";
    }
  });
}
```

Then make sure you have `await` wherever you are calling it like:

```
const data = await receive("code")
//make sure this is in an async function
```